# Append file image to FormData in Javascript (Http Request)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, base64

I'm facing issues post images to web api from Ionic/Cordova App, javascript.
I reference link below
[link](http://shazwazza.com/post/uploading-files-and-json-data-in-the-same-request-with-angular-js/)

This is my code:

```
$http({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: url,
                          headers: {
                          //'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                          //'Content-Type': false,
                          //'Content-Type': undefined,
                          'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                          'DevicePassword': localStorage.getItem("UserPassword"),
                          'UserName': 'thuong'
                          },
                          transformRequest: function (data) {
                          var formData = new FormData();
                          formData.append("data", angular.toJson(data.data));
                          alert("sizeofImg: " + data.files.length);

                          for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
                                alert(data.files[i].ImgSrc);
                                var blob = dataURItoBlob(data.files[i].ImgSrc);
                                //var file = new File([blob], "file.png",{type: 'image/png');
                                formData.append("file" + i, blob, "filename" + i + "png");
                          }
                          return formData;
                          },
                          data: { data: jsonData, files: files }
                          })
             .then(function (result) {
                   alert("success" + result);
                   success(result);
            },
                   function (error) {
                   alert("error" + JSON.stringify(error));
                   failure(error);
                   }
            );

function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
// convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
var byteString;
if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
    byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
else
    byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

// separate out the mime component
var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

// write the bytes of the string to a typed array
var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
}

return new Blob([ia], {type:mimeString});
```

}

In there, data.files[i].ImgSrc is base64 String. (I used Cordova Camera plugin to get it)
It's start like: data:image/png;base64, ...
It alway fall in fail callback, with status code: 415 (UnsupportMediaFile).I implemented server side like link above.
Does dataURIToBlob method right ? 
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

append upload file see code blow

```
$scope.updateProfile = function(form_data){
        console.log(form_data);
        $scope.submitted = true;
        $scope.reg = form_data;
         var fd = new FormData();
         var file = $scope.fileToUpload;
         fd.append('file',file);
         $http.post(API_URL+"user_update_profile", fd, {
             transformRequest: angular.identity,
             headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
            })
            .success(function(res){
                 console.log(res);
            })
            .error(function(err){
                 console.log(err);
            });
    }
```

Note: fileToUpload variable is file attribute

```
   var file = $scope.fileToUpload;
     fd.append('file',file);
```

Comment: I have only base64 string, I dont use component <input t type="file"/>. And where is $scope.fileToUpload ?

Comment: use file attribute code    <input accept="image/*" name="file" ng-value="fileToUpload" value="{{fileToUpload}}" file-model="fileToUpload" set-file-data="fileToUpload = value;" type="file" id="my_file" />     Above code apply this file attribute without base64 string this can work.

Comment: Sorry. I not use input tag, cause my task is get image from camera plugin. So i only have base 64. I converted it to BLOB, now i dont know how to publish it.

Comment: <img data-ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{user.data}}" data-err-src="images/png/profile.png"/>